# TensorFlow accuracy metrics

Tags: tensorflow, keras, regression, classification, metrics

The following is a very simple `TensorFlow` 2 image classification model.
Note that the loss function is not the usual `SparseCategoricalCrossentropy`. Also, the last layer has only 1 output, so this is not the usual classification setting. The accuracy here does not have meaning, but I am just curious.

So this code does not work well as we expected, but still produces outputs with an accuracy of around 10%, which seems reasonable.

My question is how this accuracy is calculated? The prediction from this model is a continuous value and the y_true is an integer value. It is not impossible to have an x.0 for the prediction, then the accuracy is too high.

```
import tensorflow as tf

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
])

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10)

===

Epoch 1/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 3s 1ms/step - loss: 1.8237 - accuracy: 0.0922
Epoch 2/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 3s 1ms/step - loss: 1.8266 - accuracy: 0.0931
Epoch 3/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 3s 1ms/step - loss: 1.8335 - accuracy: 0.0921
Epoch 4/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 3s 1ms/step - loss: 1.8109 - accuracy: 0.0931
Epoch 5/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 3s 1ms/step - loss: 1.8210 - accuracy: 0.0926
Epoch 6/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 3s 1ms/step - loss: 1.8067 - accuracy: 0.0921
Epoch 7/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 3s 1ms/step - loss: 1.8028 - accuracy: 0.0925
Epoch 8/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 3s 1ms/step - loss: 1.8070 - accuracy: 0.0929
Epoch 9/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 3s 1ms/step - loss: 1.7879 - accuracy: 0.0925
Epoch 10/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 3s 1ms/step - loss: 1.8055 - accuracy: 0.0914
<tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks.History at 0x7f65db17df10>
```

So, I have searched the `TensorFlow` API document to find the following example. And it makes sense.

```
m = tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy()
m.update_state([[1], [2], [3], [4]], [[0], [2], [3], [4]])
m.result().numpy()

===

0.75
```

So I have tried the following code and get the 0.0 accuracy.

```
m = tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy()
m.update_state(model.predict(x_train), y_train)
m.result().numpy()

===

0.0
```

Is there any explanation for this?

Comment: Accuracy is just mean of y_true == y_pred, that does not change, note that using accuracy here makes no sense since its a regression problem.

Comment: I agree. The accuracy does not make any sense here. I am just curious how TensorFlow got this number.

Answer (score 0):

look at the shapes of `y_true` and `y_pred` metrices, because their shape is [n,1] not the [n] | (where `n` is number of instances).
so, you have to [expand the shape](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/expand_dims) over the -1 axis.

Comment: Can you copy and run the code? I cannot explain it even if I expand the shape.